# How to show variable's value in Dialog Name (Einstein Bot)

Tags: salesforce, chatbot, salesforce-einstein

I need to show the Product's Name in the Menu, I think image says it all:

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7R7u.png)

I have a menu, with two options, and the first show a text with a variable, but {!Product} don't works, there is a way of this work?

When I put {!Product} in Message or Question, this works normal...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't find any solution for showing the variable in the title dialog, my solution was to change the message to "Know more about this product", I left a generic message.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but the answer might help someone.

There's a great article explaining how to get some dynamic information https://www.infallibletechie.com/2021/11/how-to-create-case-from-einstein-bot.html

In your case, I guess you need to

1. Query your products (the out-of-the-box Einstein Bot query is simple and has a limit of 3 items but you could call a flow or apex to get better granularity on the filter/logic and control le size)
2. Store the query result in a Custom record list Variable
   [Query data with a flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5FLZ.png)
3. Use a dynamic question and merge fields to display what you want

[Top configuration of the dynamic question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT5KN.png)
[Down configuration of the dynamic question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcz2z.png)